# How to generate Pivot Table with multi-level headers from Object?

Tags: javascript, json, object, html-table, pivot-table

I want to generate HTML table from given 2 objects, but it has too many nested headers and I can't seem to manage.

Here is what the final result should look like:

[image]

And here is the data I am given to create the table:

```
var columnData = [  {Col001: "1",Col002: "John Barnes",Col003: "Martha Hall",Col004: "Small",Col005: "Has a Drive-Thru",Col006: "Dustin Kensrue", ScorePct: "84.7"},
                {Col001: "2",Col002: "John Barnes",Col003: "Martha Hall",Col004: "Small",Col005: "Has a Drive-Thru",Col006: "Dustin Kensrue", ScorePct: "93.8"},
                {Col001: "2",Col002: "John Barnes",Col003: "Martha Hall",Col004: "Small",Col005: "Has a Drive-Thru",Col006: "Ninja Koto", ScorePct: "87.5"},
                {Col001: "3",Col002: "Russell Montgomery",Col003: "Judith Rodriguez",Col004: "Small",Col005: "Has a Drive-Thru",Col006: "Dustin Kensrue", ScorePct: "90.3"},
                {Col001: "4",Col002: "Russell Montgomery",Col003: "Judith Rodriguez",Col004: "Small",Col005: "Has a Drive-Thru",Col006: "Ninja Koto", ScorePct: "83.3"},
                {Col001: "5",Col002: "Russell Montgomery",Col003: "Alice Butler",Col004: "Medium",Col005: "Has a Drive-Thru",Col006: "Ed Waves", ScorePct: "90.3"},
                {Col001: "6",Col002: "Russell Montgomery",Col003: "Alice Butler",Col004: "Medium",Col005: "Has a Drive-Thru",Col006: "Ed Waves", ScorePct: "87.5"},
                {Col001: "7",Col002: "Russell Montgomery",Col003: "Stephen Peterson",Col004: "Medium",Col005: "No Drive-Thru",Col006: "Dustin Kensrue", ScorePct: "90.6"},
                {Col001: "7",Col002: "Russell Montgomery",Col003: "Stephen Peterson",Col004: "Medium",Col005: "No Drive-Thru",Col006: "Ed Waves", ScorePct: "68.8"},
                {Col001: "7",Col002: "Russell Montgomery",Col003: "Stephen Peterson",Col004: "Medium",Col005: "No Drive-Thru",Col006: "Ninja Koto", ScorePct: "83.3"},
                {Col001: "8",Col002: "John Barnes",Col003: "Stephen Peterson",Col004: "Large",Col005: "No Drive-Thru",Col006: "Ninja Koto", ScorePct: "80.0"},
                {Col001: "8",Col002: "John Barnes",Col003: "Stephen Peterson",Col004: "Large",Col005: "No Drive-Thru",Col006: "Veela Faint", ScorePct: "96.9"},
                {Col001: "9",Col002: "John Barnes",Col003: "Russell Taylor",Col004: "Large",Col005: "No Drive-Thru",Col006: "Ninja Koto", ScorePct: "88.9"},
                {Col001: "10",Col002: "Russell Montgomery",Col003: "Carl Perry",Col004: "Large",Col005: "No Drive-Thru",Col006: "Ed Waves", ScorePct: "87.5"},
                {Col001: "10",Col002: "Russell Montgomery",Col003: "Carl Perry",Col004: "Large",Col005: "No Drive-Thru",Col006: "Veela Faint", ScorePct: "93.8"}];

var rowData = [ {ColID:"0",ColValue:"101",RowID:"1"},
            {ColID:"1",ColValue:"Varna",RowID:"1"},
            {ColID:"0",ColValue:"102",RowID:"2"},
            {ColID:"1",ColValue:"Dobrich",RowID:"2"},
            {ColID:"0",ColValue:"103",RowID:"3"},
            {ColID:"1",ColValue:"Plovdiv",RowID:"3"},
            {ColID:"0",ColValue:"104",RowID:"4"},
            {ColID:"1",ColValue:"Montana",RowID:"4"},
            {ColID:"0",ColValue:"105",RowID:"5"},
            {ColID:"1",ColValue:"Sofia",RowID:"5"},
            {ColID:"0",ColValue:"106",RowID:"6"},
            {ColID:"1",ColValue:"Sliven",RowID:"6"},
            {ColID:"0",ColValue:"107",RowID:"7"},
            {ColID:"1",ColValue:"Pomorie",RowID:"7"},
            {ColID:"0",ColValue:"108",RowID:"8"},
            {ColID:"1",ColValue:"Albena",RowID:"8"},
            {ColID:"0",ColValue:"109",RowID:"9"},
            {ColID:"1",ColValue:"Bourgas",RowID:"9"},
            {ColID:"0",ColValue:"110",RowID:"10"},
            {ColID:"1",ColValue:"Bansko",RowID:"10"}];
```

**About columnData object:**

columnData.**Col001** represents each row number of the table.

columnData.**Col002** to columnData.**Col005** are the headers of the table, where 001 is the highest level, 005 the lowest level.

columnData.**ScorePct** the corresponding values for each row

**About rowData object:**

rowData.**RowID** - number of the row

rowData.**ColID** - number of the column

rowData.**ColValue** - the corresponding value

Here is the solution I came up with so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/u5c21mg3/1/

I managed to build another object from this two (you will see it in the console from the jsfiddle) but i cannot print it properly. Or maybe there is better way to build the third object? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://fiddle.jshell.net/jddz3jgz/2/

Here is my partial solution - grouping by points.
I'll be glad if I was able to help but unfortunately I wasn't able to come up with a solution for the headings

***UPDATE:***

Full solution:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/jddz3jgz/3/